# Asp.Net duplicates from database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, distinct, viewbag, actionresult

There is a table with news and categories Id (many to many). I want to deduce news without duplicates, but the Distinct method does not help. How to solve the problem?

```
ViewBag.NewsToCategory = db.News_To_Category.Where(db=>db.News.Status == 1).Distinct().ToList();
```

Html Code

```
@foreach(News_To_Category nw in ViewBag.NewsToCategory)
    {
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 hidden-sm">
            <div class="blog-home blog-box">
                <div class="blog-top-desc">
                    <div class="blog-date">
                        @Convert.ToDateTime(nw.News.Dates).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")
                    </div>
                    <h4>@nw.News.Title</h4>
                    <i class="fa fa-user-o"></i>
                    <strong>admin</strong>
                    <i class="fa fa-commenting-o"></i>
                    <strong>8 comments</strong>
                </div>
                <img style="min-width:370px;max-width:370px;min-height:240px;max-height:240px" src="~/Uploads/@nw.News.Image">
                <div class="blog-btm-desc">
                    <p>
                        @nw.News.Content;
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-min btn-solid">
                        Read More
                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Comment: In the News_To_Category table, there are several rows with the same news IDs attached to different categories, I want to print only the News with this table, but without duplicates, but the same news is displayed several times, not including Dictinct (), how else to disable news output from

Comment: Can you not include `NewsCategory` in the where clause?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. Filter on status = 1 and order descending on date. Group by the Ids to get duplicates and then select the first of each group.

```
ViewBag.NewsToCategory = db.News_To_Category.Where(db=>db.News.Status == 1).OrderByDescending(x => x.News.Dates)).GroupBy(x => x.News.Id).Select(x => x.News.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry friend, but GROPBY() "Does not exist in the current content"((

Comment: @Самир Гасанов Did you spell it like that with a "u". GroupBy is an extension method in the Linq library for IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>. From what I can tell from your code and what you said, you are using Linq to SQL on a DbSet which definitely has GroupBy.

Comment: @СамирГасанов were you able to make this solution work?